# Check mobile data is on from sim one or sim two android

Tags: java, android, networking

Is there anyway to check mobile data is active from sim 1 or sim 2 in Android programmatically??

Also i want to get the carrier provider in which the data is active.

Eq : 
sim 1 : carrier 1
Sim 2 : carrier 2

If data is active on sim 2 
It should return the carrier 2 name.

Answer (score 2):

my way (Android >= 22)

```
int getDefaultDataSubscriptionId(final SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager)  {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)  {
            int nDataSubscriptionId = SubscriptionManager.getDefaultDataSubscriptionId();

            if (nDataSubscriptionId != SubscriptionManager.INVALID_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)  {
                return (nDataSubscriptionId);
            }
        }

        try  {
            Class<?> subscriptionClass = Class.forName(subscriptionManager.getClass().getName());
            try {
                Method getDefaultDataSubscriptionId = subscriptionClass.getMethod("getDefaultDataSubId");

                try {
                    return ((int) getDefaultDataSubscriptionId.invoke(subscriptionManager));
                }
                catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (SubscriptionManager.INVALID_SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
    }

    @TargetApi(22)
    public String getUIText22(final TelephonyManager telephonyManager) {
        SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager) getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);

        int nDataSubscriptionId = getDefaultDataSubscriptionId(subscriptionManager);

        if (nDataSubscriptionId != SubscriptionManager.INVALID_SUBSCRIPTION_ID) {
            SubscriptionInfo si = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfo(nDataSubscriptionId);

            if (si != null) {
                return (si.getCarrierName().toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to get current active data sim operator for dual sim environment. It works after api level 22.

```
    public static String getDataSimOperator(Context context) {
        if (context == null) {
            return null;
        }

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (tm != null) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    int dataSubId = SubscriptionManager.getDefaultDataSubscriptionId();
                    TelephonyManager dataSimManager = tm.createForSubscriptionId(dataSubId);
                    return dataSimManager.getSimOperator();
                } else {
                    String operator = getDataSimOperatorBeforeN(context);
                    if (operator != null) {
                        return operator;
                    } else {
                        return tm.getSimOperator();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return tm.getSimOperator();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
    private static String getDataSimOperatorBeforeN(Context context) {
        if (context == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int dataSubId = -1;
        try {
            Method getDefaultDataSubId = SubscriptionManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDefaultDataSubId");
            if (getDefaultDataSubId != null) {
                getDefaultDataSubId.setAccessible(true);
                dataSubId = (int) getDefaultDataSubId.invoke(null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (dataSubId != -1) {
            SubscriptionManager sm = (SubscriptionManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
            if (sm != null && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SubscriptionInfo si = sm.getActiveSubscriptionInfo(dataSubId);
                if (si != null) {
                    // format keep the same with android.telephony.TelephonyManager#getSimOperator
                    // MCC + MNC format
                    return String.valueOf(si.getMcc()) + si.getMnc();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```