# Check which sim card is with mobile data on

Tags: android, networking, android-networking, telephony

I need to check if mobile data is on. There are severial questions here telling us how to do that, but none of them refer to issue of the Dual sim devices.

```
public Boolean isMobileDataEnabled(){
    Object connectivityService = getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) connectivityService;

    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        return (Boolean)m.invoke(cm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(e instanceof NoSuchMethodException){

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            {
                boolean isDataEnabled = Settings.Global.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), "mobile_data", 0) == 1;
                return isDataEnabled;
            }
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**The problem is if there is any way to discover which sim card is with mobile data active ?**

I tried checking with telephony manager but it doesn't solve any problem.

EDIT: I discovered subscriptionmanager, but that is only from api 22 up. What about lower versions?

Comment: How to get mobile data on using subscriptionmanager ? can you help me ?

Comment: Looks similar please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823886/check-mobile-data-is-on-from-sim-one-or-sim-two-android