# On Android dual sim phone, how to detect which SIM card has data enabled?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I'm writing a network monitor app. I want to detect which SIM card in a dual SIM phone has data enabled?

I have tried TelephonyManager.isDataEnabled() methods for both SIM cards. But the method returns enabled for both SIMs. Instead I should be getting enabled for one SIM card and disabled for the other.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {

    SubscriptionManager subManager = (SubscriptionManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
    List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfoList = subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        TelephonyManager mgr = telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(subscriptionInfoList.get(0).getSubscriptionId());
            int isDataEnabledSIM1 = mgr.isDataEnabled()?1:0;

            mgr = telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(subscriptionInfoList.get(1).getSubscriptionId());
            int isDataEnabledSIM2 = mgr.isDataEnabled()?1:0;

            Log.d(TAG, "isDataEnabledSIM1: "+isDataEnabledSIM1 + ", isDataEnabledSIM2="+isDataEnabledSIM2);
    }
}
```

Both isDataEnabledSIM1 and isDataEnabledSIM2 are returned as 1 indicating data is enabled on both SIMs. This is obviously incorrect, I am expecting 1 only for one SIM card and 0 for the other.

Comment: Looks similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823886/check-mobile-data-is-on-from-sim-one-or-sim-two-android

Answer (score 0):

You can use getDefaultDataSubscriptionId() from SubscriptionManager (For N and higher) and under N you can use reflection. Example:

```
public static int getDefaultDataSubscriptionId(Context context) {
    SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        subscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        int nDataSubscriptionId = SubscriptionManager.getDefaultDataSubscriptionId();

        if (nDataSubscriptionId != SubscriptionManager.INVALID_SUBSCRIPTION_ID) {
            return (nDataSubscriptionId);
        }
    }

    try {
        Class<?> subscriptionClass = Class.forName(subscriptionManager.getClass().getName());
        try {
            Method getDefaultDataSubscriptionId = subscriptionClass.getMethod("getDefaultDataSubId");

            try {
                return ((int) getDefaultDataSubscriptionId.invoke(subscriptionManager));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                return ERROR_CODE_EXCEPTION_HANDLED;
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                return ERROR_CODE_EXCEPTION_HANDLED;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            return ERROR_CODE_NO_SUCH_METHOD;
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return ERROR_CODE_EXCEPTION_HANDLED;
    }
}
```